# Config STemWin correct to use the FlexColor driver with the ST7735 display driver

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

I tried to get the STM32F446ZE and the STemWin Library running in a Keil Project.
The used OS is embOS from Segger.
I tried to follow the instructions from ST to display "hello world" on the display.
I use the display driver ST7735S which should be supported by the FlexColor driver.
My problem is that instead of "hello world" the display stays white.
I configured GUIConf.h like that:

```
#define GUI_NUMBYTES  0x8000
```

In GUI_x I added the following in GUI_X_init() :

```
void GUI_X_Init(void) {
    UC_ST7735_init();
    USInt current = Sopas_usiGet_IOLink14360ST7735DisplayBacklightCurrent();
    LITA_setDisplayCurrent((uint8_t)current);
}
```

In UC_ST7735_init() the SPI-Port gets intiated. This part should work because it ist already used in the same sensor type. The only difference is, that I removed the graphcis library we used before. The addition lines activate the display and it's backlight.

In LCDConf_FlexColor_Template.c I set the resolution like this:

```
#define XSIZE_PHYS  100 // To be adapted to x-screen size
#define YSIZE_PHYS  40 // To be adapted to y-screen size
```

The follwing three methods I filled like that:
It should be metioned that UC_ST7735_writeSPI4Wire was also used before and should work. It sends one byte after each other instead of 16 bit at once.
I tried to send the high byte and the low byte in different orders.

```
static void LcdWriteReg(U16 Data) {
    uint8_t data[2];
    UC_ST7735_dcFLAG_t dcFlag = UC_ST7735_COMMAND;
    data[0] = (uint8_t)UTIL_HLP_LOW_BYTE_OF_INT16(Data);
    data[1] = (uint8_t)UTIL_HLP_HIGH_BYTE_OF_INT16(Data);
    UC_ST7735_writeSPI4Wire(&data[1], 1, dcFlag);
    UC_ST7735_writeSPI4Wire(&data[0], 1, dcFlag);
}
static void LcdWriteData(U16 Data) {
    UC_ST7735_dcFLAG_t dcFlag = UC_ST7735_DATA;
    uint8_t data[2];
    data[0] = (uint8_t)UTIL_HLP_LOW_BYTE_OF_INT16(Data);
    data[1] = (uint8_t)UTIL_HLP_HIGH_BYTE_OF_INT16(Data);
    UC_ST7735_writeSPI4Wire(&data[1], 1, dcFlag);
    UC_ST7735_writeSPI4Wire(&data[0], 1, dcFlag);
}
static void LcdWriteDataMultiple(U16 * pData, int NumItems) {
    UC_ST7735_dcFLAG_t dcFlag = UC_ST7735_DATA;
    uint8_t data[2];
    int start_size = NumItems;
  
    while (NumItems--) {
        data[0] = (uint8_t)UTIL_HLP_LOW_BYTE_OF_INT16(pData[start_size-NumItems]);
        data[1] = (uint8_t)UTIL_HLP_HIGH_BYTE_OF_INT16(pData[start_size-NumItems]);
        UC_ST7735_writeSPI4Wire(&data[1], 1, dcFlag);
        UC_ST7735_writeSPI4Wire(&data[0], 1, dcFlag);
  }
}
```

I didn't change LCD_X_Config()

```
void LCD_X_Config(void) {


  GUI_DEVICE * pDevice;
  CONFIG_FLEXCOLOR Config = {0};
  GUI_PORT_API PortAPI = {0};
  //
  // Set display driver and color conversion
  //
  pDevice = GUI_DEVICE_CreateAndLink(GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR, GUICC_565, 0, 0);
  //
  // Display driver configuration, required for Lin-driver
  //
  LCD_SetSizeEx (0, XSIZE_PHYS , YSIZE_PHYS);
  LCD_SetVSizeEx(0, VXSIZE_PHYS, VYSIZE_PHYS);
  //
  // Orientation
  //
  Config.Orientation = GUI_SWAP_XY | GUI_MIRROR_Y;
  GUIDRV_FlexColor_Config(pDevice, &Config);
  //
  // Set controller and operation mode
  //
  PortAPI.pfWrite16_A0  = LcdWriteReg;
  PortAPI.pfWrite16_A1  = LcdWriteData;
  PortAPI.pfWriteM16_A1 = LcdWriteDataMultiple;
  PortAPI.pfReadM16_A1  = LcdReadDataMultiple;
  GUIDRV_FlexColor_SetFunc(pDevice, &PortAPI, GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR_F66708, GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR_M16C0B16);
}
```

The code I run is:

```
 GUI_Init();       
    int xPos, yPos;
    //__HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_ENABLE();    
        
    xPos = LCD_GetXSize() / 2;
    yPos = LCD_GetYSize() / 3;
    GUI_SetFont(GUI_FONT_COMIC24B_ASCII);
    GUI_DispStringHCenterAt("Hello world!", xPos, yPos);

    // Endless loop:
    while(true)
    {
        OS_TASK_Delay(100);
        MW_TWD_arm(); // Arm the watchdog
    }
```

There is no Compile-Error and the Watch Dog does not cause a problem. 
The problem is that the display stays white. 
I noticed that the command number which the flexchain driver sends over spi does not match the excpeted numbers from the St7735 datasheet.
I debugged the SPI method. The follwing commands and data got sent.

- a command with  0x00 as the high byte
- a command with  0x03 as the low byte. As far I know there is no command number 3 for theSTt7735
- data with  0x00 as the high byte
- data with  0x00 as the low byte
- a command with  0x00 as the high byte
- a command with  0x50 ('P') as the low byte.
- data with  0x00 as the high byte
- data with  0x00 as the low byte
- a command with  0x00 as the high byte
- a command with  0x51 ('Q') as the low byte.
- data with  0x00 as the high byte
- data with  0x63 as the low byte
- a command with  0x00 as the high byte
- a command with  0x52  as the low byte.
- data with  0x00 as the high byte
- data with  0x00 as the low byte ...
- after a while with more alternating commands and data there is just data with 0x00

Did I forget to config something?

---

Update:
​Changing GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR_F66708​ to GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR_F667089 helped in order to get the right command numbers for the ST7735 display driver.

Changing GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR_M16C0B16​ to GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR_M16C1B8​ doesn't. My device reboots before any SPI communication happens.

I debugged the program to known when The error occurs.

I runs the following methods without crashing but after the last one I didn't see an other name of a method in the disassmbly window of Keil.

emwin_LCD_init

LCD_SETBk_ColorIndex

LCD_set_ClipRectMax

GUI_Alloc_getFixedBlock

GUI_Device_GetpDriver

GUIDRV_Flexcolor_InitOnce

GUI_Alloc_getFixedBlock

LCD_X_DisplayDriver

It get's to the end of LCD_X_DisplayDriver​ but never to LcdWriteReg​, LcdWriteData​, LcdWriteDataMultiple​ or LcdReadDataMultiple​.

What could be the problem?